# Select rows that match all specified rows using a join table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying write a query which would return all programs that have category a and category b. The table structure is as follows:

Program

```
id
1000
1001
1002
```

Program_Category

```
program_id | category_id
1000       | 1
1000       | 2
```

Category

```
id          | name
1           | category a
2           | category b
```

As you can see program 1000 has category a and category b. The query i am trying to use to retrieve the program is

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id 
FROM PROGRAM t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (PROGRAM_CATEGORY t2 
                 JOIN CATEGORY t0 ON (t0.id = t2.category_id)
) ON (t2.program_id = t1.id) 
WHERE ((t0.name = 'category a') 
   AND (t0.name = 'category b'))
```

This is currently returning 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular `JOIN` can do it in a fairly straight forward way;

```
SELECT pc1.program_id 
FROM program_category pc1
JOIN program_category pc2
  ON pc1.program_id = pc2.program_id
JOIN category c1
  ON c1.category_id = pc1.category_id AND c1.name = 'category a'
JOIN category c2
  ON c2.category_id = pc2.category_id AND c2.name = 'category b'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1dfe/5).

Comment: Thanks this worked. Looks like I was missing having a join per category that I wanted to search on.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't guess what your query is trying to do but I think this will work for you

```
SELECT count(*), p.ID FROM Program p
INNER JOIN Program_Category pc ON pc.program_id = p.id
INNER JOIN Category c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE c.category_name = 'category a' or c.category_name = 'category b'
GROUP BY p.ID HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

This will get any program wich appears twice matching any of these categories.

This will NOT work if (program_id, category_id) is NOT a UNIQUE KEY.
I mean, this will fail if Program_Category can have twice the pair 1000,1

Answer (score 0):

Try joining with two instances of `category`. This query checks that `p` is related with a ' category a' and a 'category b', and will work even if a `(program_id, category_id)` is not unique:

```
SELECT distinct p.id
FROM PROGRAM p JOIN program_category pc1 ON p.id = pc1.program_id
       JOIN category c1 ON pc1.category_id = c1.id
       JOIN program_category pc2 ON p.id = pc2.program_id
       JOIN category c2 ON pc2.category_id = c2.id
WHERE c1.category_name = 'category a'
AND c2.category_name = 'category b';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing t0.id which is actually t0.category_id according to your table definition.

Comment: That was a typo, it should be id, not category id, I have fixed by tabled definition. Thanks